# javascript creating HTML dropdown with dates

Tags: javascript

I want to create a drop down that contains dates in decreasing order. For instance, start with the current month in format "6 2012" all the way to "3 2011".

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsAZv/5/) and this is the code:

```
var TheStartDate = new Date(2011, 4, 2);
var TheCurrentDate = new Date();

TheCurrentDate = new Date(TheCurrentDate.getUTCFullYear(),
                          TheCurrentDate.getMonth(), 2);

var TheHTML = '<select>';

do {

    TheHTML = TheHTML + '<option>';
    TheHTML = TheHTML + (TheCurrentDate.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString() + " ";
    TheHTML = TheHTML + TheCurrentDate.getFullYear();
    TheHTML = TheHTML + '</option>';

    TheCurrentDate.setMonth(TheCurrentDate.getUTCMonth() - 1);

} while (TheStartDate.getTime() !== TheCurrentDate.getTime());

TheHTML = TheHTML + '</select>';

alert(TheHTML);

document.getElementById('TheTestDiv').innerHTML = TheHTML;
```

I am not too far but I think I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Seem to work fine (when I tested it in local browser). You don't even need any JS libraries, last line could be something direct like  
    document.getElementById('#TheTestDiv').innerHTML = TheHTML;  
When I tried it like this - it worked as designed.

Comment: @Trekstuff: The select control still doesn't render.

Comment: ok, nevermind, I fixed it. The problem was that it was stopping just at the month before TheStartDate. I just needed to subtract a month from TheStartDate and it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried it in normal browser, not JSFiddle? I copied your code as is and this is how it renders: http://oi48.tinypic.com/2nbyc5w.jpg

Comment: I don't know what was wrong initially but I also fixed the rendering of the jsfiddle with the line you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var toDate = new Date(2011, 2, 1);
var theDate = new Date();

var jDateSelect = jQuery('<select />');

do {
    var jDateOption = jQuery('<option />');
    jDateOption.text((theDate.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString() + " " + theDate.getUTCFullYear());
    theDate.setMonth(theDate.getMonth() - 1);
    //add the jQuery
    jDateSelect.append(jDateOption);
} while (theDate.getTime() >= toDate.getTime());



$('#TheTestDiv')
    //clear
    .html('')
    //append object
    .append(jDateSelect);
```